# Retrofit does not close connection where seems it should

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

After the timeout the following code

```
        @Throws(ApiException::class)
        inline fun <reified R> execute(call: Call<R>): R {
        var response: Response<R>? = null
        try {
            response = call.execute() //line (main.kt:137) THE ONE STACKTRACE POINTS TO!!
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            //SHOULD close connection
            throw ApiException.NetworkError(response?.errorBody()?.string() ?: DEFAULT_REASON, cause = e)
        }
        if (response != null && response.isSuccessful)
            try {
                return response.body()!!
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                response.errorBody()?.close()
            }
            //SHOULD close connection
            throw ApiException.ServiceRespondedNegative(response.errorBody()?.string() ?: DEFAULT_REASON)
        }
```

throws

```
java.lang.Throwable: response.body().close()
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.getStackTraceForCloseable(Platform.java:148)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.captureCallStackTrace(RealCall.java:89)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:73)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at com.example.client.functional.Api$analyze$1$doResume$$inlined$get$1$1.invoke(main.kt:137)
    at com.example.client.functional.MainKt$runInAsyncContext$1$1.doResume(main.kt:97)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:150)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:14)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I've tried lots of combinations of `try`/`catch`/`finally`
The stacktrace points to `execute()` method call at `(main.kt:137)`
Don't  know how and where to close body.
tried call `raw().close()`, `string()` all over the place, 
still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
    @Throws(ApiException::class)
    inline fun <reified R> execute(call: Call<R>): R {
    var response: Response<R>? = null
    try {
        response = call.execute() //line (main.kt:137) THE ONE STACKTRACE POINTS TO!!
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        //SHOULD close connection
        throw ApiException.NetworkError(response?.errorBody()?.string() ?: DEFAULT_REASON, cause = e)
    }
    if (response != null && response.isSuccessful)
        try {
            return response.body()!!
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            response.errorBody()?.close()
        }
    else response.close() // something like this line was forgotten.
        //SHOULD close connection
        //throw ApiException.ServiceRespondedNegative(response.errorBody()?.string() ?: DEFAULT_REASON)
    }
```